# while creating table i got missing right parenthesis error in sql plus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have tried to create below table.and getting above error,please correct the code.

```
CREATE TABLE HostelInfo
(
Hostelid NUM(20),
Hostelname VARCHAR2(10)
);
/
```

Comment: @AbeMiessler this is clearly an Oracle question (sqlplus in title + VARCHAR2 data type)

Answer (score 3):

`NUM(20)` is an invalid data type; try `NUMBER(20)` instead:

```
CREATE TABLE HostelInfo
(
    Hostelid NUMBER(20),
    Hostelname VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct data type is `NUMBER`:

```
CREATE TABLE HostelInfo
(
  Hostelid NUMBER(20),
  Hostelname VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4).